# iptables can't block timestamp request with CentOS

Tags: linux, iptables, icmp, timestamp

I am setting up firewall with iptables on my host.  I want to disable timestamp ICMP request, but it's wired, I only allows type 8 (echo-request) comes into host, but event still, I can get timestamp from my host

```
64 bytes from xxxxxxxxx: icmp_seq=2 ttl=61 time=2.56 ms
TS:     36654775 absolute
        -6423
        3
        1
        -4
        0
        4
        0
        -2
Unrecorded hops: 1
```

I try to allow type 8 only, but it doesn't work, it appears that all I can do is to let all ICMP requests pass, or deny all of them, following is the configuration script I'm using.

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -Z
iptables -P INPUT   DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT  ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED -j ACCEPT

# allow the icmp
iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT

# services
iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --dport 22 -j ACCEPT # SSH
iptables -A INPUT -p UDP --sport 53 -j ACCEPT # DNS
iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --sport 53 -j ACCEPT # DNS
iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --dport 80 -j ACCEPT # HTTP
iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --dport 443  -j ACCEPT   # HTTPS

# allow the replay from outgoing established connection
iptables -A INPUT -p TCP -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

The version of Linux kernel is 2.6.18, and the version of iptables is v1.3.5.  What's wrong with that?  How to block time stamp requests?

Comment: What you are doing (blocking ICMP TS) is a rare practice. You might elaborate more on what you are doing, and why. This could be interesting.

Comment: For security reason, the report of security scanning shows that the timestamp might be a weakness.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the timestamp option of `ping`, and it looks like the ICMP type remains at 8 and that the timestamp request is apart of the IP options.  This is probably why you are not filtering the requests since they look just like regular echo requests to `iptables`.

There is a match extension called ipv4options you might want to explore for blocking the timestamps.